# real time data processing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm receiving a real time data in the format below:

```
time  : price
93015 : 10450
93016 : 10450
93020 : 10500
```

as you see above, time is not returned every second. I think it returned every settled time.

I want to make Open, High, Low, Close price data in every 5 minutes.

please let me know the way.

```
ctime = com_obj.GetHeaderValue(18) #get realtime time data, type=integer
time_stamp = ctime
cur_price = com_obj.GetHeaderValue(13) #get realtime price data type=integer
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(price=cur_price, time_stamp=time_stamp)).set_index('time_stamp').sort_index()
```

here is my code above. and when i coding 4th line then error message is poped-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `resample()` function with `ohlc` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#from io import StringIO  # if you use python 3.x
from StringIO import StringIO  # if you use python 2.x

raw_data_string_buffer = 'time  : price\n93015 : 10450\n93016 : 10450\n93020 : 10500\n'
print(raw_data_string_buffer)

time  : price
93015 : 10450
93016 : 10450
93020 : 10500

# replace the stringio part with your file path
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data_string_buffer), header=0, sep=':', names=['time', 'price'])

data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], format='%H%M%S')

data = data.set_index(['time'])

data.resample('5min', how='ohlc')

Out[177]: 
                     price                     
                      open   high    low  close
time                                           
1900-01-01 09:30:00  10450  10500  10450  10500
```

Comment: I'am great appreciate with your answer. but still i have problem.
Cause i am receiving 'H-MM-SS' or 'HH-MM-SS' type of data, I think my time value must be converted to 'YYYY-HH-MM-SS' type.
Or is there anyway to get time_stamp for my original data?

Comment: and i have error saying :if using all scalar values you must pass an index

Comment: @islandman346 try this to read data, `data = pd.read_csv(your_file_path, header=0, sep=':', names=['time', 'price'])` and please post the result of `data.head()`

Comment: @islandman346 what does your raw data file look like? Is is the same as the format at the beginning of your post?

Comment: @islandman346 I've modified the code. You can replace `StringIO(raw_data_string_buffer)`  in `pd.read_csv` function with your own file path. Let me know whether this works for you.

Comment: `data.resample('5min', how='ohlc')` no longer works. It has to be `data.resample('5T').ohlc().bfill()`.